# How to unit test if "." is not on @INC?

Tags: perl

I used Module::Starter to create the skeleton of a module, and one of the test files it creates ("t/00-load.t") looks like this:

```perl
#!perl -T
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

plan tests => 1;

BEGIN {
  use_ok( 'My::Module' ) || print "Bail out!\n";
}
```

But when I run `make && make test`, this test fails because turning on taint mode ("perl -T") removes "." from `@INC`, so that `My::Module` is not found. I can see the value of turning on taint checking in general, but how am I supposed to then test this code? This is the error message that's output:

```
#   Failed test 'use My::Module;'
#   at t/00-load.t line 10.
#     Tried to use 'My::Module'.
#     Error:  Can't locate My/Module.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
#     /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
#     /Library/Perl/5.16
#     /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
#     /Network/Library/Perl/5.16
#     /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
#     /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2
#     /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
#     /System/Library/Perl/5.16
#     /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level
#     /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16) at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
```

This is on perl 5.16.1, with Module::Starter 1.62 and ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.86. The skeleton was created with "module-starter --module=My::Module", so using defaults for everything else.

Comment: it shouldn't be looking in ., it should be looking under blib/??

Comment: @ysth: There is no 'blib' in `@INC`, I edited the question to add the error output.

Comment: @ysth: this is the error output with `prove t`. I should have stuck with `./Build test`. That runs with no errors.

Comment: @ysth: that runs the tests correctly, thanks! But using `./Build test` will also rebuild `blib` if it's out of sync with the source, so it's probably the right way to do it.

Comment: yes (or `make test` if a non-Build module).  but then afterwards it can be convenient to be able to `prove --blib -v t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the module is created with Module::Starter, which in turn relies on MakeMaker (or Module::Build), then all building and testing should be done via the provided Makefile (or Build file, if using Module::Build). I.e., with `make && make test` or `./Build && ./Build test`.